# Error when trying to use the lag function in explicit-pass through [Hive] [SAS over Hadoop]

Tags: hadoop, hive, sas, hiveql

The following query is giving me the error:

Execute error: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from 
       org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask

Does anyone know why or how to resolve this issue?

```
proc sql;
connect to hadoop(server='xxx' port=10000 schema=xxx SUBPROTOCOL=hive2 sql_functions=all);
execute(
create table a as
select
    *,
    lag(claim_flg,1) over (order by ptnt_id,month) as lag1
from b
) by hadoop;
disconnect from hadoop;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a limitation issue in HIVE database:

Hive Limit of 127 Expressions per Table
**Due to a limitation in the Hive database, tables can contain a maximum of 127 expressions. When the 128th expression is read, the directive fails and the SAS log receives a message similar to the following:**

ERROR: java.sql.SQLException: Error while processing statement: **FAILED:
Execution Error, return
       code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask**

ERROR: Unable to execute Hadoop query.
ERROR: Execute error.
SQL_IP_TRACE: None of the SQL was directly passed to the DBMS.
The Hive limitation applies anytime a table is read as part of a directive. For SAS Data Loader, the error can occur in aggregations, profiles, when viewing results, and when viewing sample data.

Source: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/dmddug/67908/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p1fl149uastoudn1v7r2u5ff8aft.htm